# removing space left/right on x-asix

Tags: matlab

How can I remove left /right space on x-asix.

```
hold all
set(gcf,'color','w')
L1=min(ndata_(:,1));
L2=max(ndata_(:,1));
plot(ndata_(:,1),ndata_(:,2))

NumTicks = 20;
L = get(gca,'XLim');
set(gca,'XTick',linspace(L1,L2,NumTicks))
datetick('x',13,'keeplimits', 'keepticks')
xticklabel_rotate;
set(gca,'XMinorTick','on','YMinorTick','on')
ylim([-0.2 .2])
grid on
hold off
```

[image]

```
ndata_=[41582.3596295486    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596300926    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596306366    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596313657    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596319097    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596324421    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596329861    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596335301    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596340625    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596346065    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596351505    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596356829    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596362269    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596367708    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596373032    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596378472    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596383912    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596389236    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596394676    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596400116    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596405440    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596410880    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596416319    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596423611    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596429051    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596434375    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596439815    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596445255    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596450579    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596457986    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596463310    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596468750    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596474190    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596479514    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596484954    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596490394    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596495718    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596501157    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596506597    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596512384    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596517708    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596522801    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596528588    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596535532    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596540856    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596546296    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596551736    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596557523    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596562847    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596567940    0.0154999999999995
41582.3596573727    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596579051    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596585995    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596591435    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596596875    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596606134    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596611458    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596618866    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596624190    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596629630    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596635070    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596640394    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596645833    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596651273    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596656597    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596662037    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596667477    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596672801    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596678241    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596683681    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596689005    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596694444    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596699884    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596705208    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596712616    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596719907    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596725347    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596730671    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596736111    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596741551    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596746875    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596752315    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596757755    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596766551    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596771991    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596777431    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596783218    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596788542    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596793634    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596799421    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596804745    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596810185    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596815625    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596820949    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596826389    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596831829    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596837153    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596844560    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596849884    0.0194999999999995
41582.3596855324    0.0194999999999995


]
```

downloaded xticklabelrotate from the file-exchange.

Comment: set the `xlim` as well! -> `set(gca,'xlim',[lb ub])`

Comment: also check out `axis tight` (but that tightens also the y-axis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `axis` command

```
>> axis( [ min(ndata(:,1)), max(ndata(:,1)),-.2 .2 ] )
```

Alternatively, you can use [`xlim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html):

```
>> xlim( [ min(ndata(:,1)), max(ndata(:,1))] );
```